# Unable to connect from Release Management 2013 to TFS Server 2013

Tags: tfs, release

I have been trying to set up a release management server on the same box as TFS, however When I click verify I get the following error:

404 page not found - TF400324

If I hit the URL in a browser on the same box  with the same credentials it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Thanks.

Comment: The down vote is very unfair I have spent two days researching this issue, its just not documented very well...

Comment: I didn't downvote you but your question is vague without any screenshots or detailed descriptions. You say that you clicked "verify" and got the error message. Where do you see the "verify" button/link? What version of Visual Studio and TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi The issue is with the release management software that microsoft has just released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is with TFS 2013 and release management 2013 it has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

It turns out I was being particularly stupid, essentially I wasn't using the correct URL for the TFS collection I was using a child collection. which does exist doesnt provide the collection services.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit unclear and it makes it hard to answer it. It would be very helpful to you and to anyone who uses SO(Stack Overflow) for their queries if you can share some screen shots or edit your question to clear all the related things.

**Solution :** I assume you are using Release Management 2013 just acquired by Microsoft.
I am sharing a screenshot for managing TFS on RM.
You(Your account that you are using to connect) must be having complete access of the TFS so verify first for your access rights on tfs.

[image: For establishing a tfs connection from RM 2013]

Comment: No this isn't the reason i was putting the wrong url as answered above.